# Prove that $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{2n-2k+1}=\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n+1)!!}$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

Prove that

\begin{equation}
 \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{2n-2k+1}=\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n+1)!!}
\end{equation}

This sum appears in the orthogonalization of Legendre polynomials.

Comment: How did you derive this from the orthogonalization? Also, the sum is $\frac{n!}{2}\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \frac1{(\frac12-k+n)(n-k)!k!}$

Comment: Do you really need an analytic, exact closed-form for this? You would want to provide some more context, your own thoughts, motivation, and/or intention so other users can provide better answers. It seems that you either need special functions for an analytic expression, or have to resort to an expression that is better suited for asymptotic analysis.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{split}
\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{2n-2k+1}&= \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\int_0^1 x^{2(n-k)}dx\\
&= \int_0^1\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}x^{2(n-k)}dx\\
&= \int_0^1 \left(1+x^2\right)^ndx
\end{split}$$

Comment: While I don't think this actually answers the question, this representation does correspond to an OEIS entry [A076729](https://oeis.org/A076729). Given the lack of better formulas on that page, I'm inclined to doubt that there's much more that can be said.

Answer (score 0):

You could write it as a hypergeometric expression:
$$ \frac{{}_{2}^{}{{{F_{1}^{}}}}\! \left(-n ,-n -\frac{1}{2};-n +\frac{1}{2};-1\right) }{2 n +1}$$